# How to force quit out of an infinite loop in a bash script gracefully

Tags: bash, system

I wrote a bash script that logs keycodes in a simple file. I have put the code in a while loop because I want it to log continuosly. But if I run the bash script in the terminal, the cursor just keeps blinking suggesting that the file is indeed caught in an infinte loop. Now i want to be able to quit this loop gracefully. I don't know how. Ctrl+C won't work. I just close the terminal and force quit the process. How do i break out of the while loop as and when the user feels like quitting the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get a blinking cursor you are probably not actually in a loop. You are probably expecting input. Try Ctrl+D. If that doesn't work then open a new terminal and `ps aux | grep command` where command is the name of the script you wrote and then kill the pid that is returned.

Comment: The cursor stops blinking after some time, so i know there is a loop going on. I want this script to run on startup. I want to stop the bash script by passing a flag like  `bash logger.sh -stop ` and if i want it to start again it should be something like `bash logger.sh -start ` How do i go about this?

Comment: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/ is a good start, but I can not answer your question directly. You need to find a way to stop all your processing smoothly and use that in the stop hook.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121391/7286) or [this more detailed one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48465/7286) to similar questions on unix.stackexchange.com :

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to stop the job, and send it to the background
- `kill %%` to kill the "current" or "last stopped" job

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea. What if you read value from a file, and instead an infinite loop, you test the value? Something like this:

```
while [ "`cat mytestfile`" = 0 ]; do
    //your stuff here
done
```

And you just `echo 1 > mytestfile`, if you want to stop the loop.